# How do you update a SQLAlchemy RowProxy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm working with the SQLAlchemy Expression Language (not the ORM), and I'm trying to figure out how to update a query result.

I've discovered that RowProxy objects don't support assignment, throwing an `AttributeError` instead:

```
# Get a row from the table
row = engine.execute(mytable.select().limit(1)).fetchone()

# Check that `foo` exists on the row
assert row.foo is None

# Try to update `foo`
row.foo = "bar"

AttributeError: 'RowProxy' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307238/updating-row-in-sqlalchemy-orm), which makes use of the ORM, but I'm specifically looking to use the Expression Language.

I've also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588375/can-i-assign-values-in-rowproxy-using-the-sqlalchemy), which converts the row to a dict and updates the dict, but that seems like a hacky workaround.

**So I have a few questions:**

- Is this in fact the only way to do it?
- Moreover, is this the *recommended* way to do it?
- And lastly, the lack of documentation made me wonder: am I just misusing SQLAlchemy by trying to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by updating a `RowProxy`?

Comment: I want to fetch a row from the database, then I have some python logic that chooses how to update it. Then I just want to update the row I fetched.

Comment: Then you are misusing SQLAlchemy. The usage you've described is the benefit of using an ORM. If you only want to restrict yourself to SQLAlchemy Core, then you need to do `mytable.update().values(foo=bar)`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: One question - is it possible using Declarative mapping -> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_styles.html ?

Comment: My problem using this construction is, that in this case object named Mytable has no attribute 'update'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing SQLAlchemy. The usage you've described is the benefit of using an ORM. If you only want to restrict yourself to SQLAlchemy Core, then you need to do

```
engine.execute(mytable.update().where(mytable.c.id == <id>).values(foo="bar"))
```